# Add blank line before a certain phrase in a text file in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, text, grep

I'm using Kali Linux, trying to sort out some input from Nmap. Basically, I ran a scan from NMap, and need to extract specific pieces of information from it. I've got it to show everything I need using the following command:

```
cat discovery.txt | grep 'Nmap scan report for\|Service Info: OS:\|OS CPE:\|OS guesses:\|OS matches\|OS details'
```

Essentially, each section of information I need will start with "Nmap scan report for [IP ADDRESS]"

I'd like to add to my command to have it create a blank line before every appearance of the word "Nmap", to clearly separate each chunk of information.

Is there any command I can use to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It won't be a single command (although I bet 'sed' could do the job, though I don't have that experience) but more likely a script to parse the output into the format you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use Perl.

```
perl -pe 's/^Nmap/\nNmap/'
```

Comment: Wow that is awesome, thank you so much! Only problem is it's cutting off the letter N now (showing as Map instead of Nmap) - any idea why that's happening?

Comment: Uh, it works for me. If there isn't a copy 'n paste error, then I've got no idea, sorry.

Comment: Ahh my mistake I was writing nMap instead of nNmap. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/Nmap/i
' file
```

That's a literal newline after the `i`

A demo: add a newline before each line ending with a "0" or a "5"

```
seq 19 | sed '/0$\|5$/i
'
```

```
1
2
3
4

5
6
7
8
9

10
11
12
13
14

15
16
17
18
19
```